# Commands fails when starting bash from perl but not when starting from command line, permission issues

Tags: linux, perl, bash, cgi

I have created a bash script that should be started from a perl script. When I run the bash directly from the terminal it works like a charm. But when trying to run the bash from my PERL-script I get a lot of permission errors.

Activities I do is creating files/directories/restaring apps/etc. How should I configure in order for the perl-script to be able to execute the bash without permission errors.

I execute the command from perl like this:

```
system($file, $arg);
```

Example of commands in bash:

```
exec 1>$1.log
exec 2>$1_error.log

mkdir /opt/$1
```

Example from error log for commands above:

```
[Wed Aug 10 18:17:17 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] /opt/otrsadm/newinstance.sh: line 3: comp.log: Permission denied
[Wed Aug 10 18:17:17 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] /opt/otrsadm/newinstance.sh: line 4: comp_error.log: Permission denied
[Wed Aug 10 18:17:17 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] mkdir: 
[Wed Aug 10 18:17:17 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] cannot create directory `/opt/comp'
[Wed Aug 10 18:17:17 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] : Permission denied
[Wed Aug 10 18:17:17 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.100]
```

What I am doing is creating a totally new instance of an application on an Apache. That means, the bash is creating necessary dir, copying the app to that dir, creating a new database and loading a template-dump, copying the application-specific config files for apache and exchanging some strings in that file, etc.

I am totally new doing this kind of activities so any possible help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the perl script as a CGI script? It'd be running under the webserver's UID, not your own.

Comment: Yes, running it as CGI. I start to understand what I need to do, I just don't know how to do it. 1. Identify the user that is running the script 2. Give access for that user to do what it needs to do in the different directories. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Yeah. if it's a CGI script running under Apache, you'll need to grab Apache write permissions on the directories.

Comment: By the way, the language is called "Perl", not "PERL". It's an intentional misspelling of "pearl", not an acronym.

Comment: The most things are working. Can anyone tell me why is the exec command different then the other commands (mkdir, etc.). The exec rows in my post are still giving me permission denied even though I have given the dir permission 777 (for testing...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You script is running under the same permissions as the Apache process. Good security practices require that your web server have as limited permissions as possible to change files that might themselves be run by the web server.

Since this sounds like exactly what you want to do the trick is to loosen up the permissions as little as possible to get the result you want.

My recommendation is to look into the program `sudo`. It can run programs as more privileged users, and provides some reasonable access controls. The basic idea would be to create a script that is owned, and only writable by the root user. Then allow the apache user (or httpd, or what ever your system calls the user running Apache) to execute that script through `sudo` as a user with the permission to write to `/opt`. If you can get away with executing the script as a user less privileged than root that is also good.

Assuming you have good error checking in your script and follow all good security practices you will be reasonably secure.

All that said, **strongly** consider paying an experienced, security minded developer to assist you with setting this up. Setting up a system like this requires a different mindset towords security, and that's something you can't get from an answer on SO. Otherwise you might have to explain to your boss how a 13 year old kid from some random country deleted all your companies data, or worse released it on BitTorrent.

Comment: Actually, I did give the dir where I try to create the log files in my example above permission 777 (for testing...). Still having the permission problem. The most other things are working. Getting some errors but I think they mostly are related to that the log-files aren't created. Why isn't it working creating the log files?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your current working directory is wrong in your perl script - you're trying to execute your bash commands in a directory where you don't have permissions to create directories.

Answer (score 1):

In your log, you have an error message split across lines:

```
mkdir: 
cannot create directory `/opt/comp'
: Permission denied
```

Is it possible that you Perl script is invoking you bash script with an argument that contains a newline?  (Though that wouldn't explain why the "mkdir:" is on a line by itself.)

Do you have write permission on `/opt`?

Comment: That was the problem. I have changed the permission and now it works. But as you can see in the other answers this may not be a good solution, from security point of view. Suggestion for how to solve what I want in a more secure way is highly appreciated (I have updated my answer with more info).

Answer (score -4):

change the permission of opt directory to 777 (read/write/execute by everyone)

chmod 777 /opt/

I think this might solve your problem.

Comment: I did this. Actually, I managed to create directory now. I will chmod teh other place I'm trying to do things in as well. (sorry, was to quick to answer before I found that there actually was a difference).

Comment: But it will create a whole host of other problems, mostly security related.  World writable directories are almost never a good idea, and should never be the first solution tried.  More information on the actual problem is needed, I think.

Comment: Not sure what to post more now (after updated my comment above). What I am doing is creating a totally new instance of an application on an Apache. That means, the script is creating necessary dir, copying the app to that dir, creating a new database and loading a template-dump, copying the application-specific config files for apache and exchanging some strings in that file. I can add this to the post.

Comment: @Nicsoft: If you're in a controlled environment, and understand the security tradeoffs, chmod 777 can be a quick and dirty way of making your scheme work.  Personally, I would still prefer at least giving write permission to only the apache owner, not everyone, but in practice that may not make much of a difference.  In general, having anything writable by the apache user, especially enough write permissions to actually set up a new web app, is a recipe for disaster.  You don't want hostile users of your web app to be able to write to your file system and set up new applications.

Comment: Any suggestion for how to do this in a different and more secure way? I need it to be automatic.

Comment: @Nicsoft: My primary preference would be to not do this through Apache at all, but by logging in to the machine as an administrative user and kicking off your script manually.  If it's absolutely necessary to do this through the web server, I'd look into some sort of setuid wrapper around your script to allow the apache user only restricted elevation of privileges for the purposes of your defined script.  And then I'd audit the script, the setuid wrapper, and the parts of your web application that initiates this stuff *very* carefully for security threats.